# How can I add stringbuilder (semi colon delimited) values to arraylist in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a stringbuilder that will look like something close to this smith;rodgers;McCalne etc and I would like to add each value to an arraylist.  Does anyone have any C# code to show this?

many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`myStringBuilder.ToString().Split(';').ToList()`

Comment: remi's answer is actually more in tune with the question, go upvote him! :)

Answer (score 11):

```
myArray.AddRange(myStringBuilder.ToString().Split(';'))
```

That's it

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "smith;rodgers;McCalne";
//
// Split string on spaces.
// ... This will separate all the words.
//
string[] words = s.Split(";");
var a = new ArrayList<String>();
foreach (string word in words)
{
    a.add(word);
}
```

[An example is here](http://dotnetperls.com/string-split)