# String extraction in C#

Tags: c#, string

I'm getting pretty frustrated with this, and hope the community can help me out.

I have a string, an example would be "1_ks_Males", another example would be "12_ks_Females".

What I need to do is write a method that extract's each value. So from the first example I'd want something like this:

1
ks
Males

In separate variables.

I'm sure I'm just being incredibly thick, but I just can't get it!

Comment: Wow, what a fool I feel right now. Thanks!

Comment: 13 virtually identical answers within 3 minutes...

Comment: At least he can be sure now that that's the correct way to do it ;-)

Comment: My head is hanging in shame as I type... Maybe it was the extra beer last night.

Comment: please search before post a question.

Comment: In case you don't want to just go with the crowd - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588503/what-are-the-alternatives-to-split-a-string-in-c-sharp-that-dont-use-string-spl

Comment: In my time, i haven't stackoverflow to ask these questions! The internet is too good for people today!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use `string.Split('_')`. With your input strings it will return a `string` array with three elements.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Split` function for `String`. Something like this

```
var split =  "1_ks_Males".Split('_');
var first = split[0];
var second = split[1];
var third = split[2];
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need to use [split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx):

```
var exampleString = "1_ks_Males";
var split = exampleString.split("_");

var first= split[0]; // 1
var second = split[1]; // ks
var third = split[2]; // Males
```

Answer (score 7):

```
string[] array =  "1_ks_Males".Split('_');

Assert.AreEqual("1",array[0])
Assert.AreEqual("ks",array[1])
Assert.AreEqual("Males",array[2])
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var values = "1_ks_Males".Split('_');
// values[0]: 1
// values[1]: ks
// values[2]: Males
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
var data = myString.Split("_");
var value = data[0];
var @type = data[1];
var gender = data[2];
```

Answer (score 5):

use `String.Split` which returns an array of values

```
var values = "12_ks_Females".split("_");
// values[0] == "12"
// values[1] == "ks"
// values[2] == "Females"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `split` -

```
var s = "1_ks_Males";
string[] values = s.Split('_');
```

Your values will then be contained in the `values' array -

```
var firstvalue = values[0];
var secondvalue = values[1];
var thirdvalue = values[2];
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to look into the `String.Split` method of the String class.  Here's the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

Basically, if all of your strings have the values that you require separated by a consistent character (in your example, this is an underscore character), you can use the `Split` method which will split a single string into an array of new strings based upon a specific separator.

For example:

```
string s = "1_ks_Males";
string[] v = s.Split('_');
Console.WriteLine(v[0]);
Console.WriteLine(v[1]);
Console.WriteLine(v[2]);
```

would output:

```
1
ks
Males
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

Like: `string[] splitParts = "1_ks_Males".Split('_');`

Answer (score 4):

Use [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) function of the string for it:

```
var variables = "1_ks_Males".Split(new char[]{'_'}, StringSplitOptions.IgnoreEmpty);
```

Now `variables[0] == "1"`, `variables[1] == "ks"`, and `variables[2] == "Males"`

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
var values = myString.Split('_');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var splitVar =  "1_ks_Males".Split('_');
var firstVar = splitVar[0];
var secondVar = splitVar[1];
var thirdVar = splitVar[2];
```

Comment: Edit this, the downvoters may to choose to clean downvote if you correct the answer, if you delete - it never happens

Comment: @OlegDok: Downvotes on deleted answers don't count towards your reputation.

Comment: @OlegDok: Only until you [recalc your reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation).

Answer (score 3):

You can use Split function provided by String. Read more about it @ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
var data = "1_ks_Males".Split('_');
```