# Running time of string.Split method

Tags: c#, .net

Following the responses to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067152/splitting-string-without-string-split), I am curious to know what is the running time of String.Split()

```
string source = "source string;this,"; //length n
string[] splitted = source.Split(' ',',',';'); //delimiter array of length m
```

Is it O(m*n) ?

Comment: You could benchmark this. I certainly cannot find documentation for the complexity.

Comment: Why not open up the source and take a look?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Comment: @mydogisbox Where can I find it.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso Running time is not there in the page.

Comment: you have to run your benchmark as it is not even on MSDN

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/90d6eeed-b7a3-494a-8c90-5035f8465622/) thread, it's *O(N)*:

> Internally, it uses a 2 pass routine.  In the first pass, the index of the separator characters are discovered and stored.  In the second pass, the string is "split" by calling Substring repeatedly and storing the results in an output array using the indices previously saved.
>
> As such, the algorithm is effectively O(N), since it's doing linear passes through the input string.

*Note: it seems that author of the statement above is [SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey) - maybe he can help with more detailed answer.*

If you want to check the sources yourself, download tool such as **[ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx)**, reference `mscorlib` and search for `Split` implementation.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/90d6eeed-b7a3-494a-8c90-5035f8465622/algorithm-behind-stringsplit-method?forum=netfxbcl